# How to change a div top margin without leaving a white space?

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles with the top margin of the "Lorem ipsum". I tried changing the margins of both div's but I couldn't figure out how to increase the upper margin of the text without creating a white space.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5aa2u6s5/1/)

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <a href="#">Inicio</a>
            <a href="otras/servicios.html">Servicios</a>
            <a href="otras/contacto.html">Contacto</a>
        </ul>
    </div>



    <div id="container">
        <div id="contenido">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
```

And here the CSS:

```
    body {

    margin: 0;
    font: 'Roboto';

}

#nav {

    height: 50px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #B18904;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav a {

    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;

}

#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #c79905;
}

#container {

    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #F5F5DC;

}

#contenido p {

    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 50px;
  background-color: #F5F5DC;
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for padding, not margin try adding to `#contenido p`

```
padding-top:10px;
```

For more information look into CSS Box Model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

Answer (score 1):

You wan to use padding instead of margin.

```
#contenido p {
    padding-top: 20px; /* Use padding*/
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 50px;
    background-color: #F5F5DC;
}
```